# How to divide result given in html() jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a function where I click a button and I get content from a `<div>`. After, I need to divide the content. I mean, if this div has 10 children, I need to save 5 children in my var `code1` and the other 5 in var `code2`. My problem is I'm not able to use html() function. My code looks like:

```
  $(".pluscontrol").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var items=$(this).closest("table").parent().next().children('#'+id).children().length;
    var middle = items / 2;
    var code1="";

    $(this).closest("table").parent().next().children('#'+id).html(
      function(index,currentcontent){
        if (index < middle )
          code1 = code1 + currentcontent;

      });

    if ( $(".modal-body .row .sdiv").attr("id") == 1 )
      $(".modal-body .row #1.sdiv").html(code1);
    if ( $(".modal-body .row .sdiv").attr("id") == 2 )
      $(".modal-body .row #2.sdiv").html("...");
  });
```

As you can see, at first, I get the children lenght but I get all items.

I've checked [this](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) reference but it not helps too much

the var **items** is the number of items

Comment: When you give an argument to `.html()` it *sets* the HTML, it doesn't return it.

Comment: `$(this).closest("table").parent().next().children('#'+id)` uhm. why not just select by id since you have one?

Comment: I know i need to optimize code but at the moment is not giving problems is the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving an argument to `.html()` makes it change the HTML of the selected elements. If you want to get the HTML, just call `.html()` with no argument.

To get the HTML of all the elements in a collection, use `.map()` to iterate, then combine them with `.join()`.

```js
var allChildren = $(".parent").children();
var middle = Math.floor(allChildren.length/2);
var code1 = allChildren.slice(0, middle).map(function(index, element) {
    return element.innerHTML + " " + index;
}).get().join(' ');
var code2 = allChildren.slice(middle).map(function(index, element) {
    return element.innerHTML + " " + (index + middle);
}).get().join(' ');

$("#out1").html(code1);
$("#out2").html(code2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Test1</div>
    <div class="child">Test2</div>
    <div class="child">Test3</div>
    <div class="child">Test4</div>
    <div class="child">Test5</div>
    <div class="child">Test6</div>
    <div class="child">Test7</div>
    <div class="child">Test8</div>
    <div class="child">Test9</div>  
    <div class="child">Test10</div>  
</div>
First group:
<div id="out1"></div>
Second group:
<div id="out2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the part about the return value.

Comment: FWIW I think it might be worth making it more explicit by using a .ceil() or .floor() on allChildren.length/2. Although what you are doing works because .slice() will truncate the decimals off of the number you pass in, for readability/maintainability sake, it is rather ambiguous to pass a non-whole number to .slice().

Comment: Also, this answer should not have a downvote.. it is a perfectly viable jQuery solution

Comment: I'm trying your first code but code1 is the whole string and code2 is undefined

Comment: My first code was wrong. `.html()` on a collection only returns the HTML of the first element, not all of them. I've removed that part of my answer.

Comment: yes, now my code is working, one last thing how can I include also its tags and attributes? because I have styles in every tag

Comment: `.html()` will return the tags in the HTML. I just made my example simple, so there are no tags in the DIVs.

Answer (score -1):

You can use querySelectorAll which gives u a collection of child element. It also has a length function which you can call. If you want you can chain a foreach method to it. I have broken it down for clarity.

```js
var children = document.querySelectorAll('.parent > div'); 
var midPoint = Math.round(children.length / 2);


var firstHalf = Array.prototype.slice.call(children,0,midPoint);
var secondHalf = Array.prototype.slice.call(children,midPoint);


firstHalf.forEach(function(elm){
    console.log(elm.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
    
    <div class="child"><p>Test1</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>Test1</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>Test1</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>Test1</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>Test1</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>Test1</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>Test1</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>Test1</p></div>
    <div class="child"><p>Test1</p></div>    
  </div>
```

Comment: What am I missing ?